# Over Ride Magento app/design/frontend/base/default/template in Custom Template

Tags: templates, magento, overriding

Im trying to over ride

```
 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/partner/logo.phtml
```

in my custom template called MyTemplate do I copy

```
paypal/partner/logo.phtml
```

under

`app/design/frontend/default/MyTemplate/template/` ?

Comment: What is your default theme set to in the Admin? (The design tab of system configuration)  What is your template folder set to in the Admin (again in the Design tab of the System Configuration)

Comment: Default theme is set to MyTemplate, Templates is set to MyTemplate, Layout is also set to the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple ways to pull this off, and the team behind Magento is neutral on "the right" way to do things, **but** the simplest way to "replace" a template is to copy the base template to the same location in your theme's template folder.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/partner/logo.phtml
app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/paypal/partner/logo.phtml
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to do, I wasn't sure what was the best way to do it.